# Y-Axis not updating at drop down filter change

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, charts

I have a bar chart with a drop down filter, and the y-axis should update once I click on the new filter but it is not and I am unsure why. The bar chart changes, but the y values stay the same. If I can have any assistance I would really love that.

Here you can find the js code below.

```
d3.csv("ContinentGraph.csv", function(error, data){

// Bar chart based on selected user's row and column
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    // Get every column value
    var elements = Object.keys(data[0])
        .filter(function(d){
            return ((d != "Continent"));
        });
    var selection = elements[0];

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
                return +d[selection];
            })])
            .range([height, 0]);

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.Continent;}))
            .range([0, width]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
            .scale(x)


    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(y)

    var svg = d3.select("#body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("id", "barchart")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height +  ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.selectAll("rectangle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class","rectangle")
        .attr("width", width/data.length)
        .attr("height", function(d){
            return height - y(+d[selection]);
        })
        .attr("x", function(d, i){
            return (width / data.length) * i ;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return y(+d[selection]);
        })
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.Continent + " : " + d[selection];
        });

    var selector = d3.select("#drop")
        .append("select")
        .attr("id","dropdown")
        .on("change", function(d){
            selection = document.getElementById("dropdown");

            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
                return +d[selection.value];})]);

            yAxis.scale(y);

            d3.selectAll(".rectangle")
                .transition()
                .attr("height", function(d){
                    return height - y(+d[selection.value]);
                })
                .attr("x", function(d, i){
                    return (width / data.length) * i ;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d){
                    return y(+d[selection.value]);
                })
                .ease("linear")
                .select("title")
                .text(function(d){
                    return d.Continent + " : " + d[selection.value];
                });

            d3.selectAll("g.y.axis")
                .transition()
                .call(yAxis);

         });

    selector.selectAll("option")
      .data(elements)
      .enter().append("option")
      .attr("value", function(d){
        return d;
      })
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      })


});
```

I also added on screen shot of how bar chart looks like.
[How bar chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dw88.png)

Also here is the csv file (not sure the proper way to post it here)

```
Continent,Max Quantity of Oil Spilled (tonnes),Total Sum Quantity of Oil Spilled (tonnes),Max Amount of Compensation  ,Total Sum of Compensation,Average Quantity of Oil Spilled (tonnes),Average Amount of Compensation,Number of Fund Type,Total Number of Unique Oil Type,Total Number of Incident,Total Number of Unique Cause of Incident
Africa,1000,1015,2952759.42,3000834.3,253.75,750208.575,2,2,4,4
Asia,29000,114033.24,3282511421,5027934340,1226.163871,54063810.11,2,8,93,11
Europe,84000,366649,261391882.7,1336112575,8332.931818,30366194.89,2,5,44,11
North America,110000,220499,164650765.2,180331907.9,20045.36364,16393809.81,2,4,11,7
South America,3600,3985.2,17914901.91,44601931.78,996.3,11150482.95,2,2,4,4
```

Comment: The class assigned to the g element is different to the class used in the selection before the transition

Comment: ok ok, this is dumb and probably just me being blind but do you mind pinpointing where did I put it that it is different? is it this code  yAxis.scale(y); ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out!

I just had to replace

```
 .ease("linear")
```

with

```
.ease(d3.easeLinear)
```

since I am using the v4 and .ease is a v3